# File name from binary stream

Tags: java, rest, sql-server-2005, image-uploading, chunking

I am working in java jersey restful web services.Here i am sending a file stream and file name as like (**httppost.setHeader("Filename:", String.valueOf(filename));**)  in the server side how to get the file name. this (**@HeaderParam("Filename:") String Filename **) gives null value.

I am working in java jersey restful web services.Here i am sending a file stream and file name as like (**httppost.setHeader("Filename:", String.valueOf(filename));**)  in the server side how to get the file name. this (**@HeaderParam("Filename:") String Filename **) gives null value.

Anyone help me in this..? 
**Its my Client POST Part**

```
inputStreamEntity = new InputStreamEntity(diStream, filesize); 
httppost.setHeader("Filename:", String.valueOf(filename)); httppost.setEntity(inputStreamEntity); 
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

**And my server (Rest service) looks lik this...**

```
public Response uploadFile(@HeaderParam("Filename:") String Filename){String uploadedFileLocation= "D://FileUpload/"+Filename;
```

Comment: Colon character looks strange here. Did you try to send/get the header without colon?

Comment: Ya i tried but same ** Null **  output.

Comment: Please show some code fragment from sender and receiver.

Comment: please add code to the question itself and remove it from comment where it is unreadable.

Comment: Did you get any solution AlexR?

Comment: No. Your code looks ok. Try to debug it to understand first whether the problem is at client or server side